# How can I make all model attributes as safe in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Here, I am making all database fields as `safe` for massive assignment?

```
[$this->attributes, 'safe', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_MIGRATION],
```

Is it correct and if not what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validation with `safe` rule for all attributes does not validate anything, so it does not make much sense. Instead of creating such rules it may be better to skip validation directly in code:

```
$model->setAttributes($data, false);
$model->save(false);
```

But if you really need such "empty" validation rules, you should use [`attributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#attributes()-detail) method to get list of attributes names:

```
[$this->attributes(), 'safe', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_MIGRATION],
```

Comment: So `setAttributes()` method will need an associative array of key and value pair?

Comment: @akshaypjoshi Yes.